# Get data values from depth image

Tags: kinect, opencv, turtlebot, ros-hydro, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a turtlebot (Create base) with a kinect. I need to save images automatically (RGB and depth images) when the turtlebot is in front of a object that is less than 1 meter away. Therefore,  i need to get access to the data values of depth image, and convert the numbers to get the distance. How can i do that ? And what's the appropriate topic to get what i need ?

For sure i'll have a code running, and since i'm new to ros i still have some silly doubts:

- My goal is to use the images on opencv. Is it necessary to install again or the one who come with ros hydro is enough ?
- When saving depth images from /camera/depth/image topic manually, i get a .jpg completely black. Anyone knows why ?
- What's the best way to get start with opencv ? How to save a image thought a C++ code and etc.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185954/get-data-values-from-depth-image/) by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-23**:
My project is kind of similar with yours, but the time I see it, it is 2016 lol. I met the same problem just as you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

You don't need to convert the data on the depth image topic manually. If you execute *roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch* you should have the topic */camera/depth/points* which is a 3D [Point Cloud](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) with the depth image converted to what you want.

About OpenCV, unless you need the bleeding edge functionalities of the ultra-super-last version, the one that comes with ROS is fairly recent and should include everything you need.

Regarding the black jpg image, the data on the topic */camera/depth/image* contains uint16 depths in mm, which is not a regular *image* that can be directly saved as jpg, you would need to convert the depth values to the range of a uchar (consequently loosing information, because uchar is only 8bits) to store it as an image.

Also, the best way to get started with opencv is to follow the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) and ask in [answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org) all your questions about the computer vision library.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thiagopj](https://answers.ros.org/users/19552/thiagopj/) on 2014-07-11**:
Actually i got the distance in meters using this function

void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr Dest=cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg);
ROS_INFO("Value: %f", Dest->image.at(msg->width/2,msg->height/2));
}

and on function main i have: ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth/image", 1000, chatterCallback);

The output is the distance in meters between the sensor and the central pixel. Using the 'points' topic whats the difference ?

I now have to transform the image received from kinect to a OpenCV image and then try to convert and save it. Any tutorial that could help with that?

Thank you for the answer!

**Comment by [rasoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26785/rasoo/) on 2016-10-23**:
why you are only interested for the depth value of center point? if I am not wrong, In your image some points or object could be more closer/far, getting the center point popnt distance does not imply that every point of the image are at same distance